# Regular Expression for a particular requirement containing word,digit and roman numbers

Tags: java, regex

I am new in using regular expression. I am trying to write a RegEx for matching like : `

> (any word+any word
>   from(class,standard,std,grade,level,semester,sem)+space(optional)+any
>   number in between 1 to 12 OR any roman number in between I to
>   XII+space+any word(optional)

RegEx should be case-insensitive.
For example: '**mathematics text book of class xi ncert**' . RegEx will match the phrase '**class xi**'.
If the string is like: '**mathematics text book of viii standard ncert**'. RegEx should not return any matching.

I have written the RegEx :

> (?i)((class|standard|std|grade|level|sem)(
>   )?(1[0-2]|[1-9]|IX|IV|V?I{0,3}|XI{0,2})(.*?|$))

Here is the piece of java code:

```
    String pattern9 = "(?i)((class|standard|std|grade|level|sem)( )?(1[0-2]|[1-9]|IX|IV|V?I{0,3}|XI{0,2})(.*?|$))";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pattern9);
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher("mathematics text book of viii standard ncert");

    if (m.find( )) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }else{
        System.out.println("No match");
    }
```

This regex works like:

```
Input : 'mathematics text book of class xi ncert'
Output : 'class'   (Expected o/p : 'class xi')


Input : 'mathematics text book of viii standard ncert'
Output : 'standard'    (Expected o/p : No match)
```

Can anyone help me to write a correct Regular expression according to my requirement?

Comment: `V?I{0,3}` since all parts are optional it can also match empty string. You probably wanted `VI{0,3}|I{1,3}` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is in the `V?I{0,3}` which allows for an empty match and does so in both your cases. You should use `VI{0,3}|I{1,3}` instead to cover it correctly.

Furthermore `(.*?|$)` is rather pointless as it will always match an empty string.